# Filtering a dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, filter

```
struct FAQList: Codable {
let valid: Bool?
let message: String?
let faqs: [String: [FAQ]]?
}

struct FAQ: Codable {
let name, question, answer: String?
}
```

is my data model.

```
{
 "valid": true,
 "message": "Faqs fetched successfully!",
  "faqs": {
    "FAQ8": [
      {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 2",
    "answer": "Answer 2"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 3",
    "answer": "Answer 3"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 4",
    "answer": "Answer 4"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 5",
    "answer": "Answer 5"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 6",
    "answer": "Answer 6"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 7",
    "answer": "Answer 7"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "Question 8",
    "answer": "Answer 8"
  },
  {
    "name": "FAQ8",
    "question": "sdrt",
    "answer": ""
  }
],
"abcs1sd122": [
  {
    "name": "abcs1sd122",
    "question": "sD",
    "answer": "ssaf"
  }
],
"ASDFG": [
  {
    "name": "ASDFG",
    "question": "kalpana",
    "answer": "UI developer"
  },
  {
    "name": "ASDFG",
    "question": "asDFGHJWQ",
    "answer": "ERTYU"
  },
  {
    "name": "ASDFG",
    "question": "sdede",
    "answer": "ERTYU"
  }
],
"test": [
  {
    "name": "test",
    "question": "ASdfg",
    "answer": "AASDFTRYU"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "question": "ASDRFT",
    "answer": "Q"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "question": "SADRTY",
    "answer": "WQEW3E45R6"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "question": "zxcVG",
    "answer": "Sadfgh"
  },
  {
    "name": "test",
    "question": "saesrtyu",
    "answer": "3q5w46e567890"
  }
]
}
}
```

is my response.

Now. I need to filter this 'faqs' dictionary to form topics list array based on keys.

Like 'FAQ8' or 'abcs1sd122' is an array consists of all questions which are having 'name' as 'FAQ8' or 'abcs1sd122' respectively.

I used this,

```
 let FAQ8 = self.viewModel.faqsList.faqs?.filter({ $0.key == "FAQ8" })
```

but it showing error.

Please advice the best method to achieve this.

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: Why are all struct members declared as optional? The JSON clearly contains all keys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all the faqs having name `FAQ8` why don't you simply write this?

```
let faqs = self.viewModel.faqsList.faqs?["FAQ8"]
```

Comment: I found that just after posting the question. Thank you for confirming.